# ERROR Internal navigation rejected - <allow-navigation> IN

Tags: ios, angularjs, iframe, ionic-framework

I'm getting the below response in my ionic app with angularJS.I tried  to open my link in angularJS iframe.

```
ERROR Internal navigation rejected - <allow-navigation> not set for url='about:blank'
ERROR Internal navigation rejected - <allow-navigation> not set for url='https://ap.testing.com/testing/testing.s/testing'
```

But i tried to add the following link in my cofig.xml but still i'm geeting same issue please advice how to fix.

```
<allow-navigation href="https://ap.testing.com/*" />
```

Answer (score 9):

I was having this problem and it turns out there are two config.xml files.

AppName/config.xml <- this one shows up in Xcode

AppName/platforms/ios/AppName/config.xml

I added

```
<allow-navigation href="*" />
```

to both of them and it worked. Using 6.3.0.

Comment: There's no need to set it in `AppName/platforms/ios/AppName/config.xml`; it's generated from the first one.